# How to tell if ERC-721 is enumerable without reverting?

Tags: solidity, erc-721

How can I tell if an NFT sent to my contract is enumerable without reverting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use EIP-165 introspection against the token contract to ask if it is enumerable.

ERC-721 specifies that contracts must implement EIP-165 to allow this kind of query.